# unexpected sleep() behavior - shared vs (vps hosting)

Tags: php, sleep

Ihave a website on goodaddy shared hosting [shame] that I am moving to one my vps linode servers [Fedora 16, apache, apc, etc...].

On the godaddy version, I have this code:

```
<?php

echo 'Do something...';
sleep(1);
echo 'Do something else...';
sleep(1);
echo 'etc...';

?>
```

When I use the same code on the linode, all of the code (including pauses) execute before the page loads. On the godaddy shared version, the content loads after each sleep [let me know if that does not sound clear]. The issue can't be browser as I use the same to view both.

Is there something I have yet to install or a setting I need to change to get the expected result.?

~ Edit: I'm not sure if this makes a difference or not but [additional info never hurts], on the linode all websites are vhosts.

Comment: What's happens if you run `php script.php` in a shell ? cut/paste the errors here if any.

Comment: It sounds like you need to disable buffering.

Comment: Hi sputnick. it works as expected, with a timed pause after sleep().

Comment: @sputnick, there were no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like they turned on output buffering. You can turn it off with [ob_end_flush()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php).